# How to parse specific texts out from rows?

Tags: sql, string

I have a table with a column name as product. Product contains product names such as bikes, sofa,desk,chair, etc. But these names come in various different free texts. For example, some may say 'books per customer' or 'table identified as...' or 'desk has no item number...'. But I need to generate a more standard product name list.
Currently I am using a lot of substrings to cut off those unwanted text strings after the names. For example:

```
case when product like '%books%' then substring(product,1,position('per cus' in product)-8)
     else produce
end as product name
```

But I need to repeat this step to capture all patterns.

I figured this is not quite efficient. Are there any better ways to do this? I even thought about to_tsvector or to_tsquery, but they won't work for a table like this, right?

Comment: Please tag the question with the type of database you are using and share a table of sample data (using DDL/DML statements) with expected results in text format to ensure reproducibility.

Comment: Your problem is not the code. Your problem is the data. You should fix it by creating new columns, such as category, type, subtype, etc and populating them with values extracted from what is apparently freeform text in existing columns. Alternatively, you could migrate your data to a NoSQL database, which is more efficient at searching freeform text.

Comment: But isn't that what I am trying to do now? To create a standardized form of product name. Unfortunately I cannot modify the original data source.